# Trouble with LocalFolderPath in UWP on different devices types

Tags: c#, uwp

I have trouble to get the local folder path in my UWP app on Mobile Emulator 10 and the Local machine with Windows 10.

My code

```
public string path { get; } = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
```

When I run the UWP app on the local machine (Windows 10) I get the path: "`...\AppData\Local\Packages\...\LocalState`". This works fine, because the folder "`LocalState`" exists.

But if I run my UWP app in the Mobile Emulator 10 I get the same path as above, but the folder "`LocalState`" doesn't exists. Instead, the name is only "`Local`" in the package for the Mobile Emulator 10.
[image]

So, how I get for Mobile Emulator the path with the directory "`Local`" at the end and for Windows 10 desktop the path with the directory "`LocalState`" at the end?

Answer (score 2):

I struggled almost 3 hrs a month ago trying to figure out why the data saved from my windows phone app was not showing up again. Then i stumbled upon [Application Data UWP Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ApplicationData). Took me 5 Mins to change my program structure and everything worked well.

Key Here is Using **ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.**

See **Scenario1_Files.xaml.cs**

There is a documentation on different Folder Types and how are they used. Pretty handy stuff.

Comment: Use ApplicationData and not Application.

Comment: Were you able to fix your problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what I am doing wrong but I get almost the path with the directory "LocalFolder" instead of "Local" at the end of the path.

Comment: can you post how you are calling the folder?